# Multithreaded C++ code deadlocks when used in Objective-C++ environment (boost, asio and thread)

Tags: c++, multithreading, macos, boost-asio, objective-c++

This is a fairly involved question, and unfortunately may involve compiling and running some code on your machine. Moreover, it's neither pure Objective-C nor it's C++, but rather using C++ from within Objective-C (i believe one might call it Objective-C++).

So, I'm using this [library](https://github.com/named-data/ndn-cpp) in my code. There's a class called `ThreadsafeFace`. For simplicity, one should think of it as an asynchronous socket (because that's what it uses underneath, in fact - unix socket). But the code I'm dealing with doesn't even get to the point where socket is being used for sending or receiving data.

Anyway, I have a C++ wrapper class `FaceProcessor` which looks like this:

**FaceProcessor.h:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>

namespace ndn {
    class Face;
}

class FaceProcessorImpl;

class FaceProcessor {
public:
    FaceProcessor(std::string host);
    ~FaceProcessor();

    void start();
    void stop();
    bool isProcessing();

    // non blocking
    void dispatchSynchronized(boost::function<void(boost::shared_ptr<ndn::Face>)> dispatchBlock);
    // blocking
    void performSynchronized(boost::function<void(boost::shared_ptr<ndn::Face>)> dispatchBlock);

    static boost::shared_ptr<FaceProcessor> forLocalhost();

private:
    boost::shared_ptr<FaceProcessorImpl> _pimpl;
};
```

**FaceProcessor.cpp:**

```
#include "face-processor.hpp"
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
#include <ndn-cpp/threadsafe-face.hpp>

using namespace ndn;
using namespace boost;
using namespace boost::asio;

class FaceProcessorImpl : public enable_shared_from_this<FaceProcessorImpl>{
public:
    FaceProcessorImpl(std::string host);
    ~FaceProcessorImpl();

    void start();
    void stop();
    bool isProcessing();

    // non blocking
    void dispatchSynchronized(boost::function<void(boost::shared_ptr<ndn::Face>)> dispatchBlock);
    // blocking
    void performSynchronized(boost::function<void(boost::shared_ptr<ndn::Face>)> dispatchBlock);

    bool initFace();
    void runFace();

private:
    std::string host_;
    shared_ptr<io_service::work> ioWork_;
    io_service io_;
    shared_ptr<Face> face_;
    thread t_;
    bool isRunningFace_;
};

shared_ptr<FaceProcessor>
FaceProcessor::forLocalhost()
{
    return make_shared<FaceProcessor>("localhost");
}

FaceProcessor::FaceProcessor(std::string host):
_pimpl(make_shared<FaceProcessorImpl>(host))
{
    if (_pimpl->initFace())
        _pimpl->runFace();
    else
        throw std::runtime_error("couldn't initialize face object");
}

FaceProcessor::~FaceProcessor() {
    _pimpl->stop();
    _pimpl.reset();
}
void FaceProcessor::start() { _pimpl->start(); }
void FaceProcessor::stop() { _pimpl->stop(); }
bool FaceProcessor::isProcessing() { return _pimpl->isProcessing(); }
void FaceProcessor::dispatchSynchronized(function<void (shared_ptr<Face>)> dispatchBlock)
{
    return _pimpl->dispatchSynchronized(dispatchBlock);
}
void FaceProcessor::performSynchronized(function<void (shared_ptr<Face>)> dispatchBlock)
{
    return _pimpl->performSynchronized(dispatchBlock);
}

//******************************************************************************
FaceProcessorImpl::FaceProcessorImpl(std::string host):host_(host)
{
}

FaceProcessorImpl::~FaceProcessorImpl()
{
    stop();
}

void FaceProcessorImpl::start()
{
    if (!isRunningFace_)
        if (initFace())
            runFace();
}

void FaceProcessorImpl::stop()
{
    if (isRunningFace_)
    {
        isRunningFace_ = false;
        face_->shutdown();

        std::cout << "work reset" << std::endl;
        ioWork_.reset();

        std::cout << "t join" << std::endl;
        t_.join();

        std::cout << "stopped" << std::endl;
    }
}

bool FaceProcessorImpl::isProcessing()
{
    return isRunningFace_;
}

void FaceProcessorImpl::dispatchSynchronized(boost::function<void (boost::shared_ptr<ndn::Face>)> dispatchBlock)
{
    if (isRunningFace_)
    {
        shared_ptr<Face> f = face_;
        io_.dispatch([dispatchBlock, f](){
            dispatchBlock(f);
        });
    }
}

void FaceProcessorImpl::performSynchronized(boost::function<void (boost::shared_ptr<ndn::Face>)> dispatchBlock)
{
    if (isRunningFace_)
    {
        if (this_thread::get_id() == t_.get_id())
            dispatchBlock(face_);
        else
        {
            mutex m;
            unique_lock<mutex> lock(m);
            condition_variable isDone;
            atomic<bool> doneFlag(false);
            shared_ptr<Face> face = face_;

            io_.dispatch([dispatchBlock, face, &isDone, &doneFlag](){
                dispatchBlock(face);
                doneFlag = true;
                isDone.notify_one();
            });

            isDone.wait(lock, [&doneFlag](){ return doneFlag.load(); });
        }
    }
}

bool FaceProcessorImpl::initFace()
{
    try {
        if (host_ == "localhost")
            face_ = make_shared<ThreadsafeFace>(io_);
        else
            face_ = make_shared<ThreadsafeFace>(io_, host_.c_str());
    }
    catch(std::exception &e)
    {
        // notify about error
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

void FaceProcessorImpl::runFace()
{
    ioWork_ = make_shared<io_service::work>(io_);
    isRunningFace_ = false;

    shared_ptr<FaceProcessorImpl> self = shared_from_this();
    t_ = thread([self](){
        self->isRunningFace_ = true;
        while (self->isRunningFace_)
        {
            try {
                std::cout << "io run" << std::endl;
                self->io_.run();
                std::cout << "io run completed" << std::endl;
                self->isRunningFace_ = false;
            }
            catch (std::exception &e) {
                // notify about error and try to recover
                if (!self->initFace())
                    self->isRunningFace_ = false;
            }
        }
    });

    while (!isRunningFace_) ;
}
```

As can be seen, the wrapper hides `io_service`-related complexity, allowing client code to simply create processor, call `start` and `stop` at will in order to execute runloop of `io_service`. Whenever created, `FaceProcessor` starts running automatically, and stops itself upon destruction. Stopping is performed in, what I believe, a graceful manner - no calls to `io_service::stop` (as it may prevent scheduled handlers from being executed), but instead `io_service::work` is reset and `thread::join()` is invoked in order to wait for full thread completion.

Now, to the question.

The test code itself is fairly simple:

```
{
   boost::shared_ptr<FaceProcessor> f = FaceProcessor::forLocalhost();
   sleep(3);
}
```

which means, that `FaceProcessor` should finish in graceful manner with no problems. One can try out this code from the latest commit of [this branch](https://github.com/peetonn/ndn-cpp/commit/0f21c0c3f0f7198e68945841a2a53b39ba62e0d7) of the library (please, see [instructions](https://github.com/named-data/ndn-cpp/blob/master/INSTALL.md) on how to build the library, it should be fairly straightforward) and executing `bin/test-get-async-threadsafe` example.

Now, the problem is, when I test the exact same code in Objective-C, it deadlocks, i.e. for some reason, `io_service::run` never returns. I use Xcode Unit Tests for testing this code and the test case looks like this:

**FaceProcessorTests.mm:**

```
#include "face-processor.hpp"

using namespace boost;
using namespace ndn;

@interface FaceProcessorTests : XCTestCase
@end

@implementation FaceProcessorTests

-(void)testTestProcessor
{
    shared_ptr<FaceProcessor> f = FaceProcessor::forLocalhost();
    sleep(3);
}

@end
```

My original `FaceProcessor` class was written in Objective-C++ (Objective-C with `boost::asio::io_service` and `boost::thread`) and I literally spent a week debugging this case, adding debug output to io_service (BOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_HANDLER_TRACKING) and underlying `ThreadsafeFace` object from the library. When I realized that exact same code works in C++, my final effort was to port `FaceProcessor` code over to pure C++ and use this class in Objective-C wrapper class. However this didn't help - the code still deadlocks, `io_service::run()` does not return in Objective-C environment.

I can't figure out why is this happening. Quite possibly, I'm just missing something fundamentally simple. One thing I noticed - when I comment out all code from `FaceProcessor` related to `face_`, nothing deadlocks in Objective-C. Since `Face` uses just `socket` underneath (in fact, it's `boost::asio::local::stream_protocol::socket`) - could it be that sockets may work slightly differently in Objective-C runtime?

The environment is:

- MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, early 2013)
- MacOS Sierra 10.12.3
- Xcode Version 8.2.1 (8C1002)
- The project is **desktop application** (not iOS)